# finding last snapshot using boto

Tags: boto, amazon-redshift

I have read the explanation about "describe_cluster_snapshots" from ...

http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/redshift.html#boto.redshift.layer1.RedshiftConnection.create_cluster

It has an option start_time and end_time but there is no way to sort it. How do I get the id of the latest snapshot using boto?

Here is what I have tried but it does not seem to return the last snapshot.

```
mysnap=conn.describe_cluster_snapshots()

mysnapidentifier=mysnap['DescribeClusterSnapshotsResponse']['DescribeClusterSnapshotsResult']['Snapshots'][-1]['SnapshotIdentifier']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to have the sorting done on the server-side so you will have to sort on the client-side.  First, extract the list of snapshot data from the response data:

```
response = conn.describe_cluster_snapshots()
snapshots = response['DescribeClusterSnapshotsResponse']['DescribeClusterSnapshotsResult']['Snapshots']
```

The `snapshots` variable should now be a list of dictionaries where each dictionary represents one snapshot.  Each of those dictionaries will have a key called `SnapshotCreateTime` and you want to sort your list by that value.  You can do that like this:

```
snapshots.sort(key=lambda d: d['SnapshotCreateTime'])
```

This does an in-place sort so your list will now be modified to have all snapshots in ascending order of that key.  You can now just grab the last item in the list:

```
mysnapidentifier = snapshots[-1]['SnapshotIdentifier']
```

I don't use Redshift so I don't have live data to test this with but I believe that will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since I just had to do this very same thing against a collection of over 100 snapshots, here's a complete solution:

```
def list_all_snapshots(conn, cluster, snap_type=None, marker=None):
    response = conn.describe_cluster_snapshots(
            cluster_identifier=cluster,
            snapshot_type=snap_type,
            marker=marker
            )['DescribeClusterSnapshotsResponse']
    result = response['DescribeClusterSnapshotsResult']
    snapshots = result['Snapshots']
    if result['Marker']:
        snapshots += self.list_all_snapshots(conn, cluster, snap_type, result['Marker'])
    return snapshots

def pick_latest_snapshot(snapshots):
    return max(snapshots, key=lambda x:x['SnapshotCreateTime'])
```